# How to get address of Shadow SSDT?

Tags: windows-7, kernel, windbg, sql-server-data-tools

I want to get the address of SSDT and Shadow SSDT using windbg.Windbg successfully connected to vmware .which commmand i have to use to get the address of these tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command displays the symbols in all contexts that match the specified pattern `x [Options] Module!Symbol`.

```
lkd> x nt!*keservicedescriptortable*
82da2980 nt!KeServiceDescriptorTableShadow = <no type information>
82da2940 nt!KeServiceDescriptorTable = <no type information>

lkd> dps 82da2980 
82da2980  82c9f634 nt!KiServiceTable
82da2984  00000000
82da2988  00000191
82da298c  82c9fc7c nt!KiArgumentTable
82da2990  95b66000 win32k!W32pServiceTable
82da2994  00000000
82da2998  00000339
82da299c  95b6702c win32k!W32pArgumentTable
```

Comment: @darkendemon Looks like you've only accepted answers to 2 questions (out of 16) so far. Do you think you could accept some more of the correct answers?

Comment: If i use that answer and work correctly .I have said thanks.I am having low point to agree the right answer.